# PostGIS 1.5 libstdc++ error

Tags: postgis, error, linux, postgis-1.5

After some package updates on my Debian machine all my database queries involving postgis functions or types are returning:

Error message from server: ERROR:  could not load library "/usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/lib/postgis-1.5.so": /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.18' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6)

Is there a way to resolve this issue? I have to move spatial data between machines, but pg_dump also fails. Is there another way to safely dump my postgis databases?

Comment: Have you tried sudo ldconfig? Also, what version did you upgrade from and to?